# Find the area and the measure of interior angles of the rhombus $ABCD$

Tags: geometry

I have such a problem which I am really earnest to solve, but I got stuck and hope you'll help me to find a solution:

> So we have a rhombus $ABCD$(in it a circle is inscribed) in which ,we see from the picture below,
>   $M$ is the point in which $AD$ is tangent to the circle. Now, join $M$
>   with corner $C$ of the rhombus and one point appears- $N$. This point
>   determines the relation $$MN=2NC$$. The question is: determine the
>   measure of interior angles of our rhombus and its area.

Here's the graph. The first is the original one, but in the second you can see the adds I introduced(with red).

> What I did is:

- I expressed $MN=2x$ and $NC=x$;
- My purpose was to express $OE$ by means of $CN$ in order to use a trigonometric function then to find the angle, and so I did and found out that: $$OE={\sqrt6x\over 2}$$
- I got stuck here because in triangle $COE$ I've got that $tanC={\sqrt2\over2}$

[image]

[image]

> I hope you'll help me ! Thank you very much!

If you do not understand something in the content of this problem please comment and I'll correct what's wrong.

Comment: Isn't the circle touching all the four sides?

Comment: Of course it's touching, my pictures are not the best. Just consider please that's a rhombus with an inscribed circle, and excuse me please for inconvenience.

Comment: You are at two steps to solution. Find sin(OCE) = OE/CO according to CA is bisector of angle C sin(C) is 2sin(OCE)*cos(OCE). Then area of rhombus is \frac{4*OE^2}{sin(C)}.

Comment: @vaychick I don't know , may be I am doing something wrong but every time I try to use what you've proposed I get that $sin(C)={{2\sqrt2}\over3}$. There is may be something wrong with this problem.

Comment: "determine the measure of interior angles of our rhombus and its area" I don't understand this phrase. Does it mean the sum of interior angles or something else? At least you can express angle C through arcsin

Comment: We have to determine the measure of each angle in this rhombus and also its area

Comment: If i computed correctly the area would be $\frac{9x^2}{\sqrt{2}}$ angle C = $\arcsin(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3})$ and angle D is $pi - \arcsin(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3})$

Comment: Yes, but $x$ is my substitution, it's added artificially ?!

Comment: The length of sides is not defined in this task.

Comment: No and this the most interesting about this problem. The angles as you saw are not such a big problem, just I see, thanks to you, that the results are a little bit not so pleasant. But now remains to find the area of the rhombus, a really challenging task I think.